# Get window z index from window handle

Tags: .net, winapi

If I have a window handle, is there a win32 call or .net equilavent that will tell me what the z index is?

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't able to find anything that directly gives you the z-order of a window. However, you might be able to try something like the following (warning, untested!)

```
int zindex = 0;
HWND window = GetTopWindow(GetParent(targetwindow));
while (window != targetwindow) {
    zindex++;
    window = GetNextWindow(window, GW_HWNDNEXT);
    if (!window) {
        zindex = -1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: 11 years later, and even Windows 10 we still do not have any _real_ z index handling on the API level directly. You would think there'd be something by now. I've been off programming in Linux for the last 10 years and hoped by now the API could make a *little* more sense, but it seems the API is just as lacking as it ever was, not much has really changed under the hood, just a bunch of new things shoved in. (Im Talking *Windows APIs* not third party, btw --who knows there may be some secretive dll somewhere that implements it that only microsoft devs know about off paper)